# Current Server time in seconds nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

I know that we can get the current server time of the Nginx server using $date_local SSI variable and redirect the URLs.

Is there any way to get the Current time showing just the "seconds" field.

Like in apache we use %{TIME_SEC}

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://{HTTP_HOST}/%{TIME_SEC}

Is there any nginx equivalent rule available?.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you could use lua or perl module for this. But what for?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I want to create a rewrite Rule like the below one on Nginx. rewrite .* http://subdomain.com/$date_local. My pronblem is that i want $date_local to be in just seconds format.

Comment: What is the underlying problem? May be you need [random index](http://nginx.org/r/random_index) module?

Comment: Actually i want to get current server time's "second" value in the URL. Is there any way i can get that value. I tried setting timefmt variable in the html source but it did not help.

Comment: There should be reason to want such a strange thing…

Comment: I am just trying to learn nginx equivalent of %{TIME_SEC} value from apache. Is that achievable?.

Comment: Yes, technically it's possible. As I write earlier with help of perl/lua module one can write anything. You could take a look at http://nginx.org/r/perl_set

Comment: Can you tell me why timefmt %S is not working in my html code?. Is it a bug?

Comment: Why do you think it should work?

Comment: Finally i was able to create a redirect using the following SSI solution.                                                             <!--# config timefmt="%S" -->
<!--# echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
<!--# if expr="$DATE_LOCAL = /^30\$/" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://mydomain.in/second/<!--# echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->"
//-->
</script>

Comment: OMG. You didn't mention SSI. Also, why not just do it in pure JS?